# Insert 3d objects (.obj) in WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, 3d, .obj

I'm beginer in WPF, and i need to insert 3d objects (.obj) in the project and do some animations on theme.
I use Visual Studio 2015.

Can you tell me the best practice? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Helix-Toolkit, that allows for more complex 3D in WPF, you can find it here: https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit

Alternatively you can install it via the Nuget Package Manager:
`Install-Package HelixToolkit.Wpf`

You can find a Getting-Started guide here: [Getting-Started](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit/wiki/Getting-started-with-WPF-3D)